# Problems with referencing to tables A1, A2 etc in appendix(with IEEEtran class)

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, ieeetran

I'm trying to refer to some tables in the appendix of my paper,
the following command have been used to number the tables as A1, A2 etc.:

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

but when I use the \ref command for cross reference, It only shows table A, not Table A1 as I wanted, will someone help figure out why the reference goes wrong?

I'm using the IEEETran class, and whit the following code:

```
\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}


some text here and refer to Table \ref{tab:app-flexible}.


\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\label{tab:app-flexible}
\caption{Parameters balabala}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
table contents...
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You have to put the `\label` after the `\caption` command like `\caption{Parameters balabala}\label{tab:app-flexible}`